# how can I use a shell script in -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, shell

I am trying to invoke a shell script on out of memory error . to do that i used this command as a argument.

```
<jdkarg value="-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='/home/host/etc/test.sh'"/>
```

but it is not working .
I also tried for

```
<jdkarg value="-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/home/host/etc/test.sh"/>
```

this also not worked for me. can anyone suggest how to use a script here .

Comment: your post seems to be missing stuff - care to share? And welcome to stack overflow

Comment: I am trying to invoke a shell script on out of memory error . to do that i used this command as a argument. <jdkarg value="-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='/home/host/etc/test.sh'"/> but it is not working . I also tried for <jdkarg value="-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/home/host/etc/test.sh"/> this also not work

Comment: can you show the output given when your app actually hits OOM?

Comment: Sorry. Was first misreading your question. Where to you put the `<jdkarg..`? The option itself looks ok to me. Is `test.sh` executable by the process which might fail?

Comment: u are asking for the executable permission for test.sh script, it 777 permission. thanks.

Comment: Ok. But how the value from `<jdkarg ...` will be used? Is it part of a build script or similar?

Comment: i used as JVM argument

Comment: (1) What does 'is not working' mean? (2) Does your script have a #! line?

Comment: @Eriko The `how` is the **important** and **missing** information. As I mentioned already the command itself is ok. If you run it as `java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/home/host/etc/test.sh YourApp` it will execute the script `test.sh` in case of an OOME.